# Copying and pasting data using VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a button on a spreadsheet that, when pressed, should allow the user to open a file, then copy columns A-G of the spreadsheet "Data", then paste the data from those columns on the current sheet.

I have a logic error in the code; it runs, but it pastes the selection in the wrong place.

I am having trouble referencing the two workbooks.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim excel As excel.Application
    Dim wb As excel.Workbook
    Dim sht As excel.Worksheet
    Dim f As Object

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    f.Show

    Set excel = CreateObject("excel.Application")
    Set wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(f.SelectedItems(1))
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Data")

    sht.Activate
    sht.Columns("A:G").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    wb.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the PasteSpecial method:

```
sht.Columns("A:G").Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

BUT your big problem is that you're changing your ActiveSheet to "Data" and not changing it back.  You don't need to do the Activate and Select, as per my code (this assumes your button is on the sheet you want to copy to).

Comment: @spookymodem, you can click the arrow and accept the answer if it did the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

'So from this discussion i am thinking this should be the code then.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim excel As excel.Application
    Dim wb As excel.Workbook
    Dim sht As excel.Worksheet
    Dim f As Object

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    f.Show

    Set excel = CreateObject("excel.Application")
    Set wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(f.SelectedItems(1))
    Set sht = wb.Worksheets("Data")

    sht.Activate
    sht.Columns("A:G").Copy
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    wb.Close
End Sub
```

'Let me know if this is correct or a step was missed. Thx.