# Auto-Updating Excel from Exportable Spreadsheet on Web

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a spreadsheet with data from the web that I need to update daily. I do this by visiting [this site.](http://www.fangraphs.com/leaders.aspx?pos=all&stats=bat&lg=all&qual=0&type=8&season=2014&month=2&season1=2012&ind=0&team=0&rost=0&age=0&filter=&players=0)

On that site, there is a link on the top right of the chart that says "export data", which downloads an Excel sheet to my machine that I then copy/paste the data from.

I know that you can auto-update excel from web tables, but how can I automatically update my data from an exportable sheet like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** Try Google "`IFTTT spreadsheet`". It should be easy to do thing.

**2** Different related Google query (more complicated but more powerful) would be "`google app script spreadsheet`"

**3** Another approach (quite popular and fun) would be Google "`node.js cheerio scraper`"

**4** if you ask just about how to do copy/paste in Excel VBA then look e.g. at [Copying and pasting data using VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778759/ms-excel-2010-copying-and-pasting-data-using-vba-code) and automatic task sheduler is built-in in all versions of Windows so you can easily place your vbscript there (see [an example](https://superuser.com/questions/599074/vbscript-in-windows-7-64bit-scheduled-task-works-with-only-run-when-logged-in))

**BTW:** the code that returns the data when you click the "export data" link comes from https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools so there may be some DataTables-specific approach available