# How to copy range to clipboard for use in another Excel instance?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two different Excel books `bk1` and `bk2` open, in two different instances so that I can have one open on each monitor.

I want an event handler for `bk1` so that when I double-click on a column in sheet `s1`, I copy all the values in that column to the clipboard, so that then I can click on `bk2` and paste these values into a column.

I have the following event handler in `bk1`, in the code module for `s1`:

```
Private Sub worksheet_beforedoubleclick(ByVal target As Range, cancel As Boolean)

Dim column As Long
Dim rng As Range

column = target.column
Set rng = Range(Cells(2, column), Cells(3233, column))
rng.Copy


End Sub
```

This event fires when I double-click, and it assigns the correct range to `rng`, but when I try to paste the values, the Paste option isn't available, even if I try to paste the values somewhere else in `bk1`.  Why isn't the range copied to the clipboard?

Note that if I change the last line to:

```
rng.Copy Sheets("sheet3").Range("a2")
```

the paste occurs successfully.  So the problem is getting the data to the clipboard.

Comment: Looks like duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778759/ms-excel-2010-copying-and-pasting-data-using-vba-code

Comment: @AlexBell, It's not.  The question you reference doesn't discuss the clipboard, and that's my main problem.

Comment: To get the data from clipboard you should use GetFromClipboard Excel VBA method (see ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278634%28v=office.15%29.aspx). Regards,

Comment: @AlexBell, that doesn't work because it concatenates all the data into a single cell.  See my response to Thinkingcap below.

Comment: Then split it into array and assign array to the range object. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At First I thought may be **Double clicking inside the cell** contents Clears the excel Clipboard

Then I open the clipboard in Excel to see if the selected data is being copied to the clipboard or not by clicking the arrow as shown below

[image]

Turns out the data is copied to the clipboard but for some reason it wouldn't paste the data

So, I finally was able to get the [clip board object with some help](http://akihitoyamashiro.com/en/VBA/LateBindingDataObject.htm)

```
Private Sub worksheet_beforedoubleclick(ByVal target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
Dim column As Long
column = target.column
Set rng = Range(Cells(2, column), Cells(3233, column))
rng.Copy

    Dim Clip As Object
    Set Clip = CreateObject( _
     "new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    Clip.GetFromClipboard
    Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlValues       

End Sub
```

Feel free to modify the Clip object to your use

Comment: I tried using the `Clip.gettext` to paste the values into a range, but it concatenated all the values into a single cell.  Try adding the line `Range("d2:q3233") = Clip.gettext` at the bottom and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Updated the code, Trynow. Replace Range("B2") to wherever you want the data

Answer (score 1):

The double-click looks to switch the cutcopymode to false