# Excel error 400 when copying to a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have looked at 100 different solutions for fixing this error that keeps showing up. its a pop up box with only the number "400" and an OK button.

the sheet im copying from is called "Front End"

My code looks like this:

```
Sub transfer()

range("C2").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Raw Data").Select
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
Selection.Paste

End Sub
```

Im just trying to get the hang of moving data from one sheet to the next empty row in another sheet but keep getting this error. any help would be greatly appreciated as I am extremely new to VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA will use whatever the active sheet is if you have not fully qualified the workbook/worksheet you want it to use.  Try something like this:

```
Sub transfer()
Dim sourceSheet as Worksheet : Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Front End")
Dim destSheet as Worksheet : Set destSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
lMaxRows = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

destSheet.Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Value = sourceSheet.range("C2").Value

End Sub
```

For copying a value directly from one place to another you don't need to use copy, paste or select; you can just set the value of one to be the value from another.

Comment: ok so i did this and used F8 to step through the code, everything was fine and dandy until it tried to do the last step "selection.paste"

I did it again and in the same place it gave me a box saying "run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: There's no `Selection.Paste` in the above code... I posted too soon and had to edit it to correct it, you may have gotten the info before my edit was submitted

Answer (score 0):

Change `Selection.Paste` to `Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` seems working for me :

```
Sub transfer()

Range("C2").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("Raw Data").Select
lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
'Selection.Paste
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Reference : [Copying and pasting data using VBA code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6778759/copying-and-pasting-data-using-vba-code)