# How to open existing excel sheets by VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-automation

I have many excel sheets named by the days of the month like `1-April, 2-April, etc`
I would like to have a code to open those sheets one by one and copy a specific range `A2:BX20` in a consolidation sheet.

The sheets are in one directory `C:\Desktop\`

I hope if anyone can help please.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your question. There are unfortunately not going to be many people here willing to write that code for you. There are however people that are willing to help you improve or fix your own code. So please show us the attempts you already made. Also to improve the quality of your question (and thus the likelihood to get an answer) see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe someone previously asked a question about looping through files in a folder here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10382861/9259306 --  I hope the answers to that question help you get some basic code.  Here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6779118/9259306) are some answers about copy&paste.  **Even if these don't help exactly** you can use the context from the Q&A's to help identify key terms to help search for more related articles / questions via google (or another search engine).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you:

```
 Sheets("NAME").Range("B3") 'B3 is the location
```

You should run for all sheets names

I hope this will help - I'm not very good at VBA.